# SSRS View Reports Suddenly Stopped - manifest.json 401 error

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2022

I have SSRS 2022 version 15.0.8264.8408

I am just doing local reports on a SQL server db located on this same laptop.

In the last week, something happened in which I can no longer view any reports in the web portal. It just hangs on the `Loading...` message.

In chrome dev tools, I get many repeated errors for `/assets/img/fi/ssrs/manifest.json` not being able to be accessed due to an 401 - Unauthorized error.

- I can click on the manifest.json and it pulls up fine in a new browser tab
- I can browse all reports fine, just not view any specific report
- I can pull up the reports in ReportBuilder and they run fine and quick
- I've restarted the computer multiple times
- I've used different browsers, cleared all site data (cache, cookies, etc)
- SQL Server Activity Monitor doesn't have any current activity. I can query data fine.
- I checked the ExecutionLog table and it shows success.

What else can this be?

[image: manifest.json error]

[image: ExecutionLog]

[image: manifest.json]